# Excluding a folder from autotesting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, restriction, autotest

I've just installed a ZenTest to use autotest in my project. I use `rspec` and have an `integration` folder inside it. As I don't want all my integration tests run every single time I start autospec , so I'd like to somehow restrict autospec from running tests in that folder.

How do I exclude a chosen folder inside a /spec from running by autotest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can tell autotest to ignore folders by editing the `.autotest` file in the root of your project:

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  %w{.git vendor spec/integration}.each {|exception| at.add_exception(exception)}
end
```

This example will ignore the `.git`, `vendor`, and `spec/integration` folders and their descendants. You'll need to restart `autospec` to make the changes effective.

Answer (score 0):

Using autotest-rails (4.1.2) and ZenTest (~> 4.5) I noticed that some of my specs weren't being run - I had a vendors_controller and vendor model, and it started picking them up when I removed vendor from the exception list and went with vendor/plugin instead.